# Как правильно перенести текст в буфер?

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста что не так? Программа не компилируется и грешит на
""  source.GetLeight()+1)  "" и "  LPCSTR(source)  ", как исправить? Спасибо большое!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Framedyn.lib")
using namespace std;

string First("* ["), second("|"), three, fifi("]"), link, source;

int main(void)
{ 
setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
//в эту переменную нужно записать текст, который в дальнейшем поместится в буфер обмена
//чтение текста из буфера обмена
cout<< "Введи название мода:";
cin>> three;

string fromClipboard;//в эту переменную сохраним текст из буфера обмена
if ( OpenClipboard(0) )//открываем буфер обмена
{
   HANDLE hData = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);//извлекаем текст из буфера обмена
   char*chBuffer=(char*)GlobalLock(hData);//блокируем память
   fromClipboard=chBuffer;
   GlobalUnlock(hData);//разблокируем память
   CloseClipboard();//закрываем буфер обмена
}
cout<< First<<fromClipboard<< second<< three<< fifi<< endl;
link=First+fromClipboard+second+three+fifi;
cout<< link<< endl;
source=link;
//запись текста в буфер обмена
if(OpenClipboard(0))//открываем буфер обмена
{
   HGLOBAL hgBuffer;
   char* chBuffer;
   EmptyClipboard(); //очищаем буфер
   hgBuffer=GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE, source.GetLeight()+1);//выделяем память
   chBuffer=(char*)GlobalLock(hgBuffer); //блокируем память
   strcpy(chBuffer, LPCSTR(source));
   GlobalUnlock(hgBuffer);//разблокируем память
   SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hgBuffer);//помещаем текст в буфер обмена
   CloseClipboard(); //закрываем буфер обмена
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Как грешит? Что пишет?

Comment: У `std::string` нет ни метода `GetLeight`, ни даже `GetLength`, так что правильно компилятор ругается.

Comment: Так а как правильно сделать, я понял, но как правильно оформить?

Comment: Оформить что? Вот вам список методов `std::string`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: Как правильно выделить память? Я всего новичок  и немного не понимаю что с этим сделать, делал по урокам и т.п.

Comment: Тогда срочно читать основы. Найдите книгу по C++ (именно книгу, видеоуроки не катят) и проштудируйте её. По поводу книг поищите вопросы на этом сайте, обсуждалось бесконечное число раз. Когда появится понимание, чем отличается `std::string` от `char*`, сможете начать писать программы.

Comment: С одной стороны, да я учусь, со второй надо сейчас :D Так, я вроде бы нашел ошибку, как подключить cstring?

Comment: @Alego22, вы имели в виду CString?

Comment: да именно CString

Comment: CString - это строки из библиотеки MFC. Скорее всего, в вашем случае, чтобы не мудрить проще создать новый проект "Консольное приложение Win32" и в окне настроек поставить галочку рядом с "Библиотека MFC".

Answer (score 1):

По поводу MS-специфичных типов удобно пользоваться сайтом MSDN или же локальной справкой MSVS. Вот, например, на этой странице можно найти, что тип CString содержится в заголовочном файле "afx.h".
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300688%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Для использования средств MFC (доступности тех же заголовочных файлов) необходимо убедиться, что по пути меню студии `Project->имя_проекта properties...->Configuration Properties->General->Project Defaults` свойство "**Use of MFC**" установлено в "**Use MFS in a** ..."

`LPCSTR` - это не класс, а синоним типа `const char*` (если навести мышь на этот тип, можно увидеть попап с текстом typedef-подстановки), читать как **L**ong **P**ointer **C**onst **S**tring, то есть длинный указатель на константную строку (в С строки - массивы char с дополнительным элементом - нульсимволом '\0'). Потому нельзя вот так вызывать "конструктор". А создается строка как всегда:

```
LPCSTR str = "Sample text";
```

В данном контексте, у класса std::string для доступа к указателю на строку в C-стиле есть метод `c_str()`, а у CString - `GetBuffer()`.

```
// для std::string source
    strcpy(chBuffer, source.c_str());

// для CString source
    strcpy(chBuffer, source.GetBuffer());

// для LPCSTR source
    strcpy(chBuffer, source);
```